# Why is 1e100+1 == 1e100 if ints do not have a maximum?

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
def factorial(n):
    import math
    if not n >= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be >= 0")
    if math.floor(n) != n:
        raise ValueError("n must be exact integer")
    if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
        raise OverflowError("n too large")
    result = 1
    factor = 2
    while factor <= n:
        result *= factor
        factor += 1
    return result
```

I don't understand why the check `n+1 == n` is needed.

I thought integers in Python have no maximum value, so why should for example `1e100+1 == 1e100`?

Answer (score 6):

`1e100` isn't an `int`; it's a `float`, so it has limited precision, and for numbers that large the precision is too low to represent the difference between `1e100` and `1e100 + 1`.

```py
>>> type(1e100)
<class 'float'>
```

If you want this number as an `int`, you can write `10 ** 100`. Then, you will get the result you expect given that Python's `int` type allows arbitrarily large integers.

```py
>>> x = 10 ** 100
>>> y = 10 ** 100 + 1
>>> x
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> y
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
>>> x == y
False
```

Comment: So you're saying that the part of the factorial() code that checks for big values is wrong?

Comment: No - it's checking that the input isn't a float that's too large. There's nothing in the function that says `n` has to be an int.

Comment: The factorial function raises an OverflowError in the case of `n+1 == n`.

Comment: Indeed; that won't be raised if `n` is an `int`, but it will be if `n` is a float that's too large.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
(10 ** 100) == (10 ** 100 + 1)       # False
(10.0 ** 100) == (10.0 ** 100 + 1)   # True
(1e100) == (1e100 + 1)               # True
```

Undoubtedly, Python's int has no maximum. But, Python's float does have a precision limit. With numbers this big, this precision limit is crossed, and for Python, these values are now the same. So, it now does not consider the 1 added. Hope it helps!